# Can't Open the Swagger page,

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

After I add swashbuckle 5.2.2 pakage. I can't open the `/Swagger` Page?

I've add the below code :

```
  protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return System.String.Format(@"{0}\bin\UnitTestingWebAPI.API.Core.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }
```

and Uncomment the code in `SwaggerConfig.cs`,but I can't open the page.

```
   c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try the FAQS page: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#troubleshooting-and-faqs

Comment: @Hackerman in fact ,I've it once, but then I can't reopen it after rebuild. I don't know why?

Comment: Check this steps, they work for me: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/

Comment: I can't add code in step2 `Swashbuckle.Bootstrapper.Init(config);` I just want to add `Swagger` for this [api Demo project](https://github.com/chsakell/webapiunittesting)

Comment: I'm gonna clone it and test the swagger package...

Comment: @thanks , BTW How exploer the `UnitTestingWebAPI.API.Core` API Document by swagger.

Comment: I was able to make it work, but, it was very hard to explain; better use this proyect as a template: https://github.com/tjoudeh/WebApiSwagger